# Is there any Chrome extension, by which I would be alerted by auto highlight when my keyword is found on a page?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions

Is there any Chrome extension, by which I would be alerted by auto highlight when my keyword is found on a page?

I do not want to use crtl+f every time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another [user script](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) which doesn't need jQuery, supports case-insensitive [regexp matching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and actually highlights the specific words you want to match:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Keyword Highlight 2
// @author         Ilmari Karonen
// @namespace      http://superuser.com/questions/467276
// @include        http://*
// ==/UserScript==

// Edit this regexp to match what you want highlighted; don't forget the "g" flag!
var r = /Chrome/ig;

// This span will be used to wrap the highlighted text:
var span = document.createElement( 'span' );
span.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

// Pre-create some other handy objects for later:
var text = document.createTextNode( '' );
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Walk the document body node by node:
var e = document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[0];
while ( e ) {
    // If it's a text node, match it against the regexp:
    if ( e.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE ) {
        var t = e.textContent, i = 0, m;
        while ( (m = r.exec( t )) !== null ) {
            // Copy any text before the match into the fragment:
            text.textContent = t.substring( i, m.index );
            frag.appendChild( text.cloneNode( true ) );
            // Wrap the match in a span and copy it into the fragment:
            span.textContent = m[0];
            frag.appendChild( span.cloneNode( true ) );
            // Keep track of the current match position:
            i = m.index + m[0].length;
        }
        if ( i > 0 ) {
            // Remove the matched text from e and re-insert it before it:
            e.textContent = t.substring( i );
            e.parentNode.insertBefore( frag, e );
            // Reset frag to a new empty fragment:
            frag = frag.cloneNode( false );
        }
    }
    // Advance to next node in DOM (bugfix: skip textarea content):
    var n = e.firstChild;
    if ( /^(head|title|script|style|textarea)$/i.test( e.tagName ) ) n = null;
    while (!n && e) {
        n = e.nextSibling;
        e = e.parentNode;
    }
    e = n;
}
```

Obligatory screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a user script like the following:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Keyword Info
// @namespace      SuperUser 467276
// @include       http://*
// ==/UserScript==

function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "jQuery.noConflict();(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}


function main() {
  jQuery('*:contains("chrome")').each(function(){
     if(jQuery(this).children().length < 1) 
          jQuery(this).css("background-color", "yellow") });
}

addJQuery(main);
```

This will highlight all *elements* (not just the matching text, as HTML doesn't work like that) that directly contain case-sensitive matches for the search string, `chrome` in the example.

This solution uses the [jQuery inclusion code from this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome). There might be problems with sites already including jQuery; you might be more successful with other solutions.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot with the highlighting of some elements on the question page]